# In jQuery, how do I get the value of a radio button when they all have the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Sales Promotion</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="1">1</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="2">2</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="3">3</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="4">4</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="5">5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Here is JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){      
        alert($('input[name=q12_3]').val());
    });
 });
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkH8n/)! Every time I click button it returns 1. Why? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

In your code, jQuery just looks for the first instance of an input with name `q12_3`, which in this case has a value of `1`. You want an input with name `q12_3` that is [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

```js
$("#submit").click(() => {
  const val = $('input[name=q12_3]:checked').val();
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sales Promotion</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="5">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Note that the above code is *not* the same as using `.is(":checked")`. jQuery's [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function returns a boolean (true or false) and not (an) element(s).

---

Because this answer keeps getting a lot of attention, I'll also include a vanilla JavaScript snippet.

```js
document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const val = document.querySelector("input[name=q12_3]:checked").value;
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sales Promotion</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="1">1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="2">2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="3">3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="4">4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q12_3" value="5">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 16):

in your selector, you should also specify that you want the checked radiobutton:

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){      
        alert($('input[name=q12_3]:checked').val());
    });
 });
```

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' value

Comment: @PavanAlapati We cannot really tell you why without seeing your HTML as well; ideally, you would post a new question with your exact HTML snippet and the code you are using. You should only get undefined though, if: The name in the selector does not match the names of the radiobuttons ; none of the radiobuttons is checked; or the checked radiobutton does not have a value assigned.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to change selector:

`$('input[name=q12_3]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 7):

There is another way also. Try below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("input[name='gender']").on("click", function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input:radio[name=q12_3]:checked').val();`

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** : https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/xygr065w/

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){      
        alert($('input:radio:checked').val());
    });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

use this script

```
$('input[name=q12_3]').is(":checked");
```

Comment: jQuery's `is` function will return a `boolean`, which in this case would be useless.