# conditional statements in jquery shortcode generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, shortcode

I want to convert this shortcode generating form into one that will generate either of two different shortcodes depending on a value selected in the form. So, a radio button says, "Which shortcode do you want to build?" Then they choose it, then they go on with the other fields to fill out the attribute values. Then when it comes time to generate the code, the JS will condition its output based on the radio button question. I've tried to modify it myself, but the problem is, this script generates the attributes from the options index, so I don't know how to include an option that doesn't go into the index:

```
var table = form.find('table');
form.appendTo('body').hide();
form.find('#myshortcodeidstem-submit').click(function(){
    var options = { 
        'shortcodename' : '', \\ THIS IS THE ONE TO DETERMINE THE SHORTCODE NAME
        'attribute' : '', \\ THIS IS THE ATTRIBUTE THAT BOTH SHORTCODES SHARE
    };
    var shortcode = '[myshortcode'; \\ THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE CONDITIONAL ON OPTION 1
        for( var index in options) {
        var value = table.find('#myshortcodeidstem-' + index).val();

        if ( value !== options[index] && value != null )
        shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
        }

    shortcode += '] Content Here [/myshortcode]'; \\ THIS LINE CONDITIONAL ON OP1
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

Barmar pointed me in the right direction, and I got it to work, but I'd like to know if there's a more economical way to do it. Here's what I have:

```
var table = form.find('table');
    form.appendTo('body').hide();
    form.find('#myshortcodeid-submit').click(function(){
        var codeselector = table.find('#myshortcodeid-codeselector').val();
        if (codeselector === '1'){          
        var options = { 
            'attribute'   : '',
            };
        var shortcode = '[shortcode_one';
            for( var index in options) {
            var value = table.find('#myshortcodeid-' + index).val();

            if ( value !== options[index] && value != null )
                shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
        }
        shortcode += '] Content Here [/shortcode_one]';
        }
        if (codeselector === '2'){          
        var options = { 
            'attribute'   : '',
            };
        var shortcode = '[shortcode_two';
            for( var index in options) {
            var value = table.find('#myshortcodeid-' + index).val();

            if ( value !== options[index] && value != null )
                shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
        }
        shortcode += '] Content Here [/shortcode_two]';
        }
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

Found a more economical way, without repeating the options index. See the answer below.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043452/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-radio-button-value?lq=1 for how to get the value of a radio button. Then uses that as an index into an array of shortcodes.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I actually got it work (I used a dropdown instead of a radio, but just for aesthetics). I'm going to update the post with it, because I want to see if there's a more economical way to do it. But it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most economic way I could come up with. Doesn't repeat the options index this way. Working good. Just had to create a var for the dropdown field that chooses the shortcode, then do if statements referencing that var's value.

```
        var codeselector = table.find('#myid-codeselector').val();
        if (codeselector === '1'){          
        var shortcode = '[shortcode_one';
        }
        if (codeselector === '2'){          
        var shortcode = '[shortcode_two';
        }
        var options = { 
            'attribute'   : '',
            };
            for( var index in options) {
            var value = table.find('#myid-' + index).val();

            if ( value !== options[index] && value != null )
                shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
        }
        if (codeselector === '1'){          
        shortcode += '] Content Here [/shortcode_one]';
        }
        if (codeselector === '2'){          
        shortcode += '] Content Here [/shortcode_two]';
        }
```