# jQuery checking radio box status and showing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a div of another set of radio boxes but only depending on which radio button is first selected.
If option option one is selected, I would like condition one div to show and if option two is selected I would like condition two div to show.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#condition-one').hide();
  $('#condition-two').hide();
  
  if ($("id=[option-one]").is(":checked")) {
  $('#visible-condition-one').show("slow");
  
  } else if ($("id=[option-two]").is(":checked")) {
        $('#visible-condition-two').show("slow");
  };
});
```

```html
<div id="always-visible">
                    <label class="control-label">Would you like option 1 or option 2</label><br>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option-info"> Option 1</label>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="option-info"> Option 2</label>
</div>

<div id="condition-one">
                    <label class="control-label">If you pick option 1, you see this div</label><br>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-three" name="option-info-group-two"> Option 3</label>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="option-info-group-two"> Option 4</label>
</div>

<div id="condition-two">
                    <label class="control-label">If you pick option 2, you see this div</label><br>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-five" name="option-info-group-three"> Option 5</label>
                    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option-six" name="option-info-group-three"> Option 6</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You're doing your tests when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks on a button.

Comment: I'm new to jquery, what would be a suggestion on fixing it?

Comment: If you want to do something when someone changes an input, use `.change()`.

Comment: @John In your demo, do you mean to say `condition-two` should be visible if `option-two` is selected?

Comment: @George yes sorry I just noticed my typo there I'll fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use jquery to get radio button value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043452/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-radio-button-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#condition-one').hide();
  $('#condition-two').hide();

  $("#option-one").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#condition-one').show("slow");
    }
  });

  $("#option-two").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#condition-two').show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

In your code, the action must be taken on user input, in this case, a radio box. You must attach a 'change' event to your radio boxes and when user changes status, the callback function is triggered.

Comment: Do I have to do something with the html? I plugged in your .js in place of mine but it' still doing the same thing. All of the elements show instead of those two being hidden.

Comment: I made an awfull mistake, i was in hury xD. Try now, I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. I never knew about the change selector, looks like I've got more studying to do.

Comment: It's the `change` event, it gets triggered on almost every user input element. More precise, on `text` input gets triggered on after `blur` event, wich means the element loses focus. Another event that could be used is `input`, it's a combination of keyboard events and change event.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
//Cache our deciding radio buttons
var $radio = $('#always-visible :radio'),

    //An array of the available radio/div identifiers
    ids = ['one', 'two'];

//Bind an event to your deciding radio buttons
$radio.change(function(){

    //That will loop through your radio buttons
    $.each(ids, function(_, n){

        //See if this one is checked
        var checked = $('#option-' + n).prop('checked');

        //If so, show the relevant block, otherwise hide it
        $('#condition-' + n).toggle(checked);
    });

//Trigger the event on page load
}).change();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chmpz7wo/)

Comment: Tho' the problem was simple, maybe for school, this is the implementation I also recommend using into a large scaling app or production, it's easy to maintain, implement for multiple cases and  fits event-driven plugins. Beginners should start saving this clever code snippets, just my advice :P

Answer (score 0):

i just did something similar(working)

```
  <html>
  <head>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#condition-one').hide();
   $('#condition-two').hide();

   $(".radio-label").on("change", function() {
   if ($('.radio-label#1').is(':checked')) {  // if the radiolabel of id=1 is checked
    $('#condition-one').show("slow");         //show condition one
    $('#condition-two').hide();                   


    } else if ($(".radio-label#2").is(":checked")) {
    $('#condition-two').show("slow");
    $('#condition-one').hide("slow");
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

      <body>

      <input type="radio" class="radio-label" id="1" name="option-info"></input>
      <input type="radio"  class="radio-label" id="2" name="option-info"></input> 


      <div id="condition-one">
      test1
     </div>

     <div id="condition-two">
      test2
    </div>
    </body>
```