# How to get value of radio button group in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldnt find the right answer for my case.

```
var inputs = $("root :input[typeof]");

// looping thru elements
inputs.each(function(index) { 
    var name = $(this).attr('name'); // get element by name (or by id)
    var value = $(this).val(); // get element value

    // How do I capture radio button (or checkbox) group 
    // element in this loop? And how do I get a checked value of such group? 
    // Note, in here $(this) should be the radio button group element
}
```

So, the question is in code comment.
How inside that loop get a value of radio button group element?

In HTML if you refer to such group by name you will automatically get the value of checked radio button in that group.

How do you do that in jQuery, when $(this) is current element in the loop?

Thanks

Comment: You know that in the time it took you to ask this question, google would have told you

Comment: What do you mean by capturing radio button...

Comment: @nicael, I didnt say anything about capturing radio button :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use jquery to get radio button value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043452/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-radio-button-value)

Comment: @RickSmith No, we don't know in advance its a radio button group

Answer (score 4):

> // Note, in here $(this) should be the radiobutton-group element

if that's the case, then this will find the value of the radio button that is checked:

```
$(this).find('input:checked').val();
```

Comment: if you have wrapped it in form then `.serialize();` would give you those too.

Comment: not good, I am looping thru unknown in advance elements, all we know we need to collect all elements with attribute typeof

Comment: Could you provide your html then? I can just go off of what you tell us. And in what way does my answer not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to check the radio inputs:

```
function CheckRadioList() {
    $('input:radio').each(function () {
        // your code here, you can storage them or do what you want.
        console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
    });
}
```

Here is a demo if you want test it: http://jsfiddle.net/jpmbL49r/

1. name: `$(this).attr('name');`
2. id: `$(this).attr('id');`
3. checked: `$(this).prop('checked')`

I hope it's helps!

Comment: it will, partially, I am more interested in radio group actually, when there is only 1 option can be selected, and that option is the value of the group

Comment: ups.. sorry @monstro my mistake .. i'll update it for radio button

Comment: @monstro Are you missing something to include in my answer and explain it to you?¿